# Copying Folder Items With GUI Variation

Tags: user-interface, powershell, copy

This code will use a `Shell.Application` COM object and use the native Windows copy dialogue to copy an item to a specified destination. The only problem is that for each immediate child folder within the source it will create separate copy dialogues.

Is there any way for me to only get 1 copy dialogue displayed so that the user can see accurate info such as overall progress, time remaining, etc.

The easiest thing I can think of so far is to either zip up the files then decompress them at the source (please, no) or to just copy the entire parent item then move the child items into place after, although I feel like that would limit the capabilities of the function.

Can anyone think of a good solution for this?

```
function Copy-ItemGUI {
    Param(
        # TODO: Allow only folder paths (Can we test these here and loop if
        # path is invalid?)
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Position=0)]
        $Source,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [string]$Destination
    )

    #If destination does not exist, break
    #TODO: Create folder if destination does not exist
    if (!(Test-Path $Destination)) {
        break
    }

    $src = gci $Source

    $objShell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"

    $objFolder = $objShell.NameSpace($Destination)

    $counter = ($src.Length) - 1
    foreach ($file in $src) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Copying file '"$file.name"' to ' $Destination '"

        try {
            #Info regarding options for displayed info during shell copy - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176633.aspx
            $objFolder.CopyHere("$source\$file", "&H0&")
        } catch {
            Write-Error $_
        }

        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Copy complete - Number of items remaining: $counter`n"
        $counter--
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not link to off-site code. Always include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't enumerate the contents of `$source` and copy each file separately. Use a wildcard for specifying the items to copy. Change your function to this:

```
function Copy-ItemGUI {
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$true,
            Position=0,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
        )]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -LiteralPath $_})]
        [string[]]$Source,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [string]$Destination
    )

    Begin {
        if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $Destination)) {
            New-Item -Type Directory $Destination | Out-Null
        }

        $objShell  = New-Object -ComObject 'Shell.Application'
        $objFolder = $objShell.NameSpace($Destination)
    }

    Process {
        $objFolder.CopyHere("$source\*", '&H0&')
    }
}
```